# How come my drag and drop list does not work in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, drag-and-drop

I'm adding a drag and drop list in my Flask application. However, the list is not draggable. What wrong with my coding?

I have tried to use the `jquery-sortable.js` library.

Code in home.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("ol.list-group-sortable").sortable();
         });
    </script>

    <div class="content-section">
        <ol class="list-group list-group-sortable" method="POST" action="">
        {% for item in things_to_sort %}
            <li class="list-group-item" id="Item-{{ item }}">{{ item }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ol>
    </div>


{% endblock content %}
```

Code in layout.html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-sortable.js') }}"></script>
```

The rendered html:

```
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/static/jquery-sortable.js"></script>

<main role="main" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("ol.list-group-sortable").sortable();
    });
    </script>

<div class="content-section">
    <ol class="list-group list-group-sortable" method="POST" action="">

        <li class="list-group-item" id="Item-Test">Test</li>

        <li class="list-group-item" id="Item-Testing">Testing</li>

        <li class="list-group-item" id="Item-Hi">Hi</li>

    </ol>
</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: What's your rendered (final) html like? Also you haven't closed your javascript function.

Comment: The function is closed and the rendered html is attached. Thanks.

Comment: Try moving your script includes above the `$(function...` code.

Comment: I have moved the script above. But it is still not working.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at `$(function() {`

Comment: Looks like jquery isn't being loaded. You sure you moved the `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/...` line above the `$(function() {..` line? Update the question with your new rendered html.

Comment: It seems I have moved it wrongly. I'm genuinely sorry. It is now working after moving the script include above the `$function...` code. Thanks a lot.